# Forms Authentication - Storing and Retrieving User Names

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

Using Forms Authentication, I am storing a cookie for each user if they mark *Remember Me* during login, using the following piece of code in the Login1_LoggedIn event.

```
if (rememberMe.Checked) FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true);
```

When the user arrives on my page with a cookie, I need to get his/her user name so I can check their roles.  Does the Forms Authentication cookie store this information, and how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you parse to SetAuthCookie (Login1.UserName in your case) will be stored in the [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) when the user accesses a page.  You can access it using:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when I check for the cookie, the user is not logged in; therefore his identity is not established, and consequently I cannot use this code.

Comment: Haha.  Ignore my last comment.  Silly me for jumping to conclusions.  +1 and Accepted for DaveG!.

Comment: It's also possible to store user roles in the authentication cookie itself and use Page.User.IsInRole("yourrole");

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: +1 cause this is correct, but DaveG beat ya so he gets accepted.  Still, thanks!